# from android gcm receive last notification only...?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I got success how to setup android gcm and related server side work in asp.net successfully.
But my issue is, It display me only last notification sent by server.

I want all notification to be display came from same **collapse_key**
or something which I change in gcm code or server side code to display all the message sent to particular device.

my code from server side is as below

```
public void SendCommandToPhone(String sCommand)
{
    String DeviceID = "";
    DeviceID = "APA91bF9SSDEp-UPU8UwvctGt5ogfrSw0UdilTWlCujqItHcr-eiPJ31ZDI-IeqTbLr92ZOPF31bXtB1_5gNEPHAq82N4ji0stm4cy9U0Yuk0Awhjl9PS02okuc9rRhJobkgOt-ofm5Br0KR-Y";
    WebRequest tRequest;
    tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    tRequest.Method = "post";
    //tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "AIzaSyBgCKDhyHnRmmu8jCfmupHVJA8cVkIa-XEZS"));
    String collaspeKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
    String postData = string.Format("registration_id={0}&data.message={1}&collapse_key={2}", DeviceID, "YourMessage", collaspeKey);
    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
    dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
    tReader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    tResponse.Close();
}
```

in android app side code is as below onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1)

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) arg0
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "meaNexus Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(arg0, Main.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    note.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, String.valueOf(R.string.app_name), message, pendingIntent);
    note.number = count++;
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, note);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=sv-SE#push)

**collapse_key**

> An arbitrary string that is used to collapse a group of like messages
>   when the device is offline, so that only the last message gets sent to
>   the client. This is intended to avoid sending too many messages to the
>   phone when it comes back online. Note that since there is no guarantee
>   of the order in which messages get sent, the "last" message may not
>   actually be the last message sent by the application server.

So you can use different collapse key for for each message if you want device to receive all the messages..

EDIT1: **Notification issue**

Following is your notification code:

```
notificationManager.notify(0, note);
```

As per the java doc of [notifiy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) method. It Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. **If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.**

So use different ID in the `notificationManager.notify()` method call to post multiple `notification` in the `notification` bar..

Comment: Thanks for reply Praful. But as you can find in my server side code that I'm using unique key(GUID) every time. But still have only one message in my notification bar when device become online

Comment: wippy, for achieve this as per your direction I change **notificationManager.notify(count, note);** thanks paraful this is what I want, thanks...!?!

Comment: Note that GCM only holds up to 4 messages at a time with different collapse keys. If you use more than 4 collapse keys at any given time, you will lose some messages. (Which messages get dropped is undefined.)

Comment: @praful Thanx, I have also overcome this problem using count in notify method. But facing a strange problem now. If my device is off or not online, then when it is on or online it should receive all notifications, which were send before. But I am not getting. I have included wake lock and same device is receiving push notification for other apps. Can you help me?????

Comment: Hi @Arjit.. please post you problem as a separate post so that other can also help you on it and I would also have more clear context about your problem.. and as Lorne said in the comment "GCM only holds up to 4 messages at a time with different collapse keys. If you use more than 4 collapse keys at any given time, you will lose some messages. (Which messages get dropped is undefined.)"

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem when I tried to implement GCM to my application.

> I used C# for my third part application. At first, I used the same
>   collapse_key for each notification. That why I received only the last
>   one.

**So, when you call your function which send the notification to your device via GCM Server, try to have a different collapse_key. 
For example try to use the curentTime.**

Comment: Thanks for reply zim, but as you can see in my server side coding in c# it uses GUID as collapse_key. So it's unique every time.